# div doesn't expand all the way horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why is there white space to the left and right of my div?

[image]

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container intro-body">
            <div className="row">
                <h2 className="intro-name center-block">TEXT</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And in my `css`:

```
.intro-body {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #3BC5C3;
}
```

I've tried to set `body` to `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`, thinking it had to do with Bootstrap's default values, but it didn't work. I also don't have a container so why does it still have padding?

Comment: what in .row class ? r u use boostrap

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap, yes.

Comment: remove .row class then check

Comment: `.row` was removed, did not solve the issue.

Comment: pls share .intro-name class css and also .center-block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the "container" class - Bootstrap also applies a styling of this - use "container-fluid" to get the full width.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid intro-body">
            <div className="row ">
                <h2 className="intro-name center-block">TEXT</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Then make sure the parent `div` of `.intro-body` don't have any padding.

Comment: I just removed center-block from the H2 and added text-center to the row - try that and see if it works. Center-block can be difficult if the parent row is not set to center. Try having the center-block in and out. The CSS behind center-block  is "0 auto", but if the parent isn't set - there may not be enough information for the calculation of auto.

Comment: Try it but i wouldn't think its required - check your CSS - is there some style conflict that is forcing the padding?

Comment: I would suggest using the Chrome Developer tools to inspect the styling around the `intro-body`. This might help you: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/?hl=en

Comment: `container-fluid` is removed in Bootstrap 3. It is now by default `container`.

Comment: No. As of now, `container-fluid` is [still there in version 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container). It is [present in version 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#containers) as well.