# container-fluid in Bootstrap 3.4 not stretching horizontally 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having the same issue as my previous question: [div doesn't expand all the way horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050830/div-doesnt-expand-all-the-way-horizontally)

All I have in my `render()` function is

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container intro-body">
        </div>
    )
```

With CSS for `intro-body` like so (for color)

```
.intro-body {
    height: 582px;
    background-color: #3BC5C3;
}
```

On full screen on a 13 inch Macbook, the left and right sides are white spaces. It seems like there's padding or margin of some sort.

[image]

But when I shrink my window to about half the size, it reaches the left and right sides

[image]

Can someone explain this strange phenomenon? Is this something in Bootstrap that I'm not aware of? I was told to use `container-fluid` but 1. I think it's removed in Bootstrap 3 and 2. It didn't work when I tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [bootstrap source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1584) you would see that `.container` has **fixed widths** for every media breakpoint except for extra small devices, and `.container-fluid` has full width for all media breakpoints:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        width: 970px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 1170px;
    }
}
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

So if you want to have fullwidth for every media breakpoint, use `.container-fluid`.

Comment: Ok, so I'm using `container-fluid`. I read somewhere that using `row` (which has -15 margins and will offset the default margins for container-fluid) should suffice, but it isn't working. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, `.row` adds negative left/right margin, which is good. To "fix" that, you must use bootstraps `.col-` elements. So, to properly use bootstrap, your grid must look like - `.container/.container-fluid` > `.row` > `.col-`. [Look at the documentation for grid system for more info](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Took a look at the documentation and followed the structure of `.container-fluid > .row > .col-xs-12` but it's displaying the same results :/

Comment: Yes, my bad - `.col-` elements also adds some padding. It should work using only `.container-fluid` > `.row`. [Check the bootply](http://www.bootply.com/EcCjo2hKvg).

Comment: Or another way would be to remove `container-fluid` padding - [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Wo8zh8JK1m)

Comment: I tried to override the padding in my CSS file for `container-fluid` class, and it still isn't working and I'm getting extremely frustrated why such a simple task is causing such a huge headache. I set `padding: 0` and `margin: 0`.

Comment: Maybe some styles are overriding it? To be sure, you can add `padding: 0 !important` which will have the highest priority.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121411/discussion-between-homerboy-and-vucko).

Answer (score 0):

First thing first : you have to put a reset css link (it must be the first one). You can find one here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/   then if you want the container to match the total width of a div element it must be a container-fluid

Comment: [Bootstrap includes normalize.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L6) so this isn't correct.